# Input values into custom class with "<<"

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I am new to C++, and I am trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a class that holds a QList. I am trying to populate the QList as demonstrated below. I am wondering how would I achieve this? Is this done in the NumberList constructor? I normally would populate myList by using a method that takes a list of objects, and extracts them to fill the QList, but that will not work for my example below.

```
NumberList myList;
myList << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

Comment: If you are using C++11 you should look at initializer list first rather than using stream operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy.

```
NumberList & operator<<(NumberList & lhs, number_t rhs)
{
    lhs.append(rhs);
    return lhs;
}
```

Or, as a member function, it would look like this:

```
NumberList & NumberList::operator<<(number_t rhs)
{
    append(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so just like the "=" operator, the "<<" operator can be overloaded as well? Cool!

Comment: @user1255869: Most operators can be overloaded.  Some have restrictions though.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to compile:
1) "Binary operator<< has too many parameters" - numberlist.h.

Comment: @user1255869: Did you make it a member?  Don't do that.  Or, if you do that, then only give it one parameter, because with member functions, the calling object (*this) is an implied first parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. In my .h file, I have NumberList& operator<< (NumberList&, int);. In the .cpp file, I have NumberList& NumberList::operator<< ( NumberList &lhs, int rhs) { ... }.

Comment: @user1255869: I added an example to my answer of how you would do it as a member function.  My original example was a free function, not a member of the class.

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of the error, but the compiler reports the following error: "<< illegal, left operand has type 'NumberList(_cdecl*)(void)" in main.cpp. The code I have there is as follows: NumberList myList(); myList << 1 << 2 << 3;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8765/discussion-between-user1255869-and-benjamin-lindley)

Comment: `NumberList myList();` declares a function returning a `NumberList`. Use `NumberList myList;` instead (no parentheses!).